# Instead of creating a database for every listview. How can I sort categories and make the list load different categories, maybe via my searchfilter?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

```
void Clickthis (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        var name = new StartPage();

        name.CategoryName ("Info1");

        Navigation.PushAsync (name);

    }

    void Clickthis1 (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        var name = new StartPage();

        name.CategoryName ("Info2");

        Navigation.PushAsync (name);
    }
```

and i push it to this function as of now :

```
    public void CategoryName (String pHeader)
    {
        productHeader.Text = pHeader;

        App.theUserCategory = pHeader;


        Application.Current.Properties ["theCategory"] = App.theUserCategory;
        Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync ();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (App.theUserCategory);
    }
```

so i store the "selectedname" in my database (theCategory), but now I want to sort the selectedname somehow so that depending on what you clicked, the listview will only show the items from that selectedname.

and maybe i can just sort if via my filter somehow???

```
    private  void FilterContacts (string filter)
    {
        EmployeeList.BeginRefresh ();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (filter)) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("if1");
            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;
        } else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("else2");
            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems.Where (x => x.irl1.ToLower ()
                .Contains (filter.ToLower ()));
            //Contains (filter.ToLower ());

        }

        EmployeeList.EndRefresh ();
    }
```

my list and the database:

```
public static List<createSomething> ourPitems = new List<createSomething>();


async void loadOurItem () ¨
    {
        var getItems = await parseAPI.getOurMainInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString ());

        EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;
        ourPitems = new List<createSomething> ();

        foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) 
        {

            ourPitems.Add (new createSomething () 
            { 
                ourName = currentItem ["listName"].ToString ()
            });

        }

        EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;
    }
```